# Structuring jinja/flask templates with multiple child templates?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm looking to design a site that provides different views of data from a database. I'm new to jinja/flask and templating in general, so it's quite likely I am going about this the wrong way and I'm looking for some feedback or "lordy lord no, you don't ever do that" feedback works too. :)

The basic structure of the page is: a header menu with quick links, a navbar menu pointing to different data sources, another navbar below that providing different views for the data. This 2nd navbar of the views would differ per option selected in the initial navbar.

I envisioned the structure of this to be something like the following:

```
|-base.html (header menu)
|--navbar1.html (extends base.html, first navbar)
|---navbar2.html (and 3 and 4, etc. - extends navbar1)
|----data_view1.html (and 2, 3, etc. - the returned query, extends navbar2)
```

This would treat each html as basically a frame and in my mind seems like the right way to do it, and use variables to track which navbar option to highlight through else blocks.

It seems messy though, what would be the best method to achieve the above? Would it be just one html file with a series of elif that would show the navbar2/3/4 and view1/2/3 pages based on what the user selects?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* do it this way, but it gets complicated really quickly.  The better solution is almost certainly to include all of your navigation in one include:

```
<nav class="top-navigation">
  <ul class="nav nav-first-level">
    {{ nav_entry("1st_ds", "1st Data Source", page, sub_page) }}
    {{ nav_entry("2nd_ds", "2nd Data Source", page, sub_page) }}
    {{ nav_entry("3rd_ds", "3rd Data Source", page, sub_page) }}
  </ul>
</nav>

{% macro nav_entry(identifier, title, page_id, sub_page_id) %}
  {% set attrs = {"class": "nav-selected"} if identifier == page_id else {} %}
  <li{{ attrs | xmlattrs }}><a href="#goes-somewhere">{{ title }}</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
      <li{{ set_if_selected('1st_sub_entry', sub_page_id) }}>1st Sub-Entry</li>
      {# Other set_if_selected calls left off for clarity) #}
      <li>2nd Sub-Entry</li>
      <li>3rd Sub-Entry</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro set_if_selected(identifier, to_match) %}
  {{ {"class": "nav-selected"} if identifier == to_match else {} | xmlattrs }}
{% endmacro %}
```

If all of these navigation entries are dynamic, then it gets even easier:

```
<nav class="top-navigation">
  <ul class="nav nav-first-level">
    {% for nav_item in navigation %}
      {{ nav_entry(nav_item) }}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`navigation` could be as simple as a list of tuples:

```
# Tuples are in the form
# (Link Title, URL, Is Selected?, Sub Menu Items)
# And sub menu items are tuples in the form
# (Link Title, URL, Is Selected?)
navigation = [("1st Data Source", "/some/url", true, []),
    ("2nd Data Source", "/some/url/2", false, [("A", "/a", false)]),
    ("3rd Data Source", "/some/url/3", false, [("B", "/b", false),("C", "/c", false)])]
```

The updates to `nav_entry` are left as an exercise for the reader :wink:

Comment: Thanks for a very clear and detailed response, Sean. I'll give this a try tonight.